# How to Create a Eclipse web service client using a wsdl document not URI?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to create a Eclipse Web Service Client using an existing WSDL document located on my machine. I need to browse for the wsdl document from my
machine

I am using Eclipse Luna version 4.1 with jdk 7 on Windows 7 OS

When I click the Browse button, I obtain this [image]

Can any one tell me how can I select the wsdl file?

[Solution] When I put my wsdl document into my project root and refreshed the project inside Eclipse, the project appeared when I clicked on browse then I can select the wsdl document

[image: now I can browse the wsdl document]

Comment: path of document?.. file extension?...

Comment: Fail.  Fail what?  Is there a stacktrace?  Also, what's your version of Eclipse?  Version of Java?  OS (Windows/Linux)?

Comment: @Pawanmishra  if u can see the image i attached when i click on browse not give me any path or root path to browse for my wsdl file this is my problem

Comment: save wsdl file within your project folder and refresh project and then try to browse wsdl file...

Answer (score 0):

Please look at following post where an example was provided with detailed steps on creating a WSDL client from a given WSDL file:
[WSDL Client from WSDL file](http://myblogmchopker.blogspot.in/2013/09/generating-web-service-java-client-from.html)

Comment: when i click on the browse button,it open on project reside in downloads folder !!! i can't change to make it browse my project root this is my big problem !!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, check the file permissions on the WSDL file : Also, confirm whether you run Eclipse as an Administrator or not.  For me, I NEED to run Eclipse as an Administrator to have certain Eclipse .metadata work in Windows 7.

So in Windows :

- Right-click the WSDL file.
- Select Properties
- Security Tab
- Locate Authenticated Users.
- Click Edit
- Set the Full Control check box.
- In Eclipse, try again.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can also supply an URI pointing to a file located in your local machine without importing the file into an Eclipse project.

The Browse button doesn't allow you to navigate your local file system but you can type the URI directly in the input box.

I have a WSDL file located in

```
D:/stackoverflow/sayhello.wsdl
```

Introducing the URI

```
file:///D:\stackoverflow\sayhello.wsdl
```

Clicking the OK button, the wizard allow me to create the web service client.

[image: Supplying a local URI]